Assigning the result to the oldest record from the given time window for a specific client
I have two tables, t1 and t2, with the same column layout: client_id, transaction_date, price, product. The first table contains main products and the second table contains additional products. I would like to check if additional products are being upsold to the same customer who purchased main products (and check price). I assume that the upsell occurs when an additional product is sold within 10 days before or after the transaction of the main product to the same client.
t1:



client_id
transaction_date
price
product




445
01.03.2024
100
main


445
01.04.2024
100
main


445
02.04.2024
100
main


339
05.04.2024
100
main


339
06.04.2024
100
main



t2:



client_id
transaction_date
price
product




445
05.04.2024
40
additional


339
05.04.2024
40
additional


339
06.04.2024
40
additional



want:



client_id
transaction_date
price
product
xsell_price




445
01.03.2024
100
main
null


445
01.04.2024
100
main
40


445
02.04.2024
100
main
null


339
05.04.2024
100
main
80


339
06.04.2024
100
main
null



I have two main problems that I cannot solve:

I would like the additional product to be assigned only to the oldest or newest matching transaction to avoid double counting. For example, if client_id = 445 purchased the main product on 01.03.2024, 01.04.2024, and 02.04.2024, and then purchased an additional product on 05.04.2024, I would like the price of the additional product to be added only to the transaction on 01.04.2024. (01.03.2024 is not included because it is older than 10 days).

An additional product can be purchased multiple times, which creates duplicates. For example, client_id = 339 purchased the main product on 01.04.2024, 02.04.2024 and then bought the additional product on 05.04.2024 and 06.04.2024, in this case, those two main transactions will be duplicated. Similar to the first point, I would like the sum of additional products to be added only to the oldest or newest main transaction.


I tried this code and it seems okay regarding the first point, but it does not solve the issue of duplicates from the second point.
with tmp as (select t1.*, 
    t2.price as xsell_price, t2.transaction_date as transaction_date_xsell 
from t1 
left join t2 on t1.client_id = t2.client_id and t2.transaction_date between (t1.transaction_date - 5) and (t1.transaction_date + 5)), 
tmp2 as (select t1.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by client_id, transaction_date_xsell order by transaction_date_xsell desc) as row_num 
from tmp) 
select t1.*, 
    case when row_num = 1 then xsell_price end as xsell_price_calc 
from tmp2;


Please provide some sample data and expected result. Describing the data and logic leaves too many open questions if there are no data too work with.

Thanks for the suggestion. I have added a sample data

Try RANK instead of row_number

One option is to define row numbers of left joined tables resultset using case expression in Partition By and Order By parts of Over() clause. Then use conditional aggregation and group by:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    t1 (CLIENT_ID,  TRANSACTION_DATE,   PRICE,  PRODUCT) AS
        ( Select 445, To_Date('01.03.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100, 'main' From Dual Union All
          Select 445, To_Date('01.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100, 'main' From Dual Union All
          Select 445, To_Date('02.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100, 'main' From Dual Union All
          Select 339, To_Date('05.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100, 'main' From Dual Union All
          Select 339, To_Date('06.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 100, 'main' From Dual 
        ), 
    t2 (CLIENT_ID,  TRANSACTION_DATE,   PRICE,  PRODUCT) AS
        ( Select 445, To_Date('05.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 40, 'additional' From Dual Union All
          Select 339, To_Date('05.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 40, 'additional' From Dual Union All
          Select 339, To_Date('06.04.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 40, 'additional' From Dual 
        )

--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    CLIENT_ID,    TRANSACTION_DATE,   PRICE,  PRODUCT, 
          Sum(Case When RN = 1 Then XSELL_PRICE End) "XSELL_PRICE"
FROM    ( Select    t1.CLIENT_ID,   t1.TRANSACTION_DATE,    t1.PRICE,   t1.PRODUCT,  
                    t2.PRICE "XSELL_PRICE",
                    Row_Number() Over(Partition By Case When t2.PRICE Is Not Null Then t1.CLIENT_ID Else 0 End, t2.TRANSACTION_DATE  
                                      Order By Case When t2.PRICE Is Not Null Then t1.TRANSACTION_DATE End, t2.TRANSACTION_DATE ) "RN"
          From      t1
          Left Join t2 ON(t2.CLIENT_ID = t1.CLIENT_ID And t2.TRANSACTION_DATE - t1.TRANSACTION_DATE <= 10)
        )
GROUP BY  CLIENT_ID,    TRANSACTION_DATE,   PRICE,  PRODUCT
ORDER BY  CLIENT_ID Desc, TRANSACTION_DATE  

/*    R e s u l t :
 CLIENT_ID TRANSACTION_DATE      PRICE PRODUCT XSELL_PRICE
---------- ---------------- ---------- ------- -----------
       445 01.03.2024              100 main            
       445 01.04.2024              100 main             40
       445 02.04.2024              100 main            
       339 05.04.2024              100 main             80
       339 06.04.2024              100 main                  */


Great skills, your code works for my problem. Thanks

@Artur You are wellcome. Could you consider accepting the answer if that is what you were looking for.
